# Using WinRT component in .NET core application

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, .net-core-3.0, c++-winrt

Is it possible to use a WinRT component in a .NET Core 3 application?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution: registration-free WinRT.

For anyone reading this please see the following articles:

- [Enhancing Non-packaged Desktop Apps using Windows Runtime Components](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/enhancing-non-packaged-desktop-apps-using-windows-runtime-components/)
- [Identity, Registration and Activation of Non-packaged Win32 Apps](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/10/29/identity-registration-and-activation-of-non-packaged-win32-apps/)

There is also this [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/RegFree_WinRT) with an example.